# Как запретить изменения масштаба встроенной карты колесиком?

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть на сайте google-карта. Если при прокрутке страницы мышка оказывается на карте, то изменяется масштаб карты, а страница не прокручивается.

Как отключить масштабирование карты при наведении курсора на карту?

Comment: Может создать прозрачный блок поверх карты? Но тогда картой вообще никак нельзя будет управлять

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В 3-ей версии API достаточно свойству **scrollwheel** объекта [MapOptions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MapOptions) присвоить **false**.

Подробнее на stackoverflow: **[How to disable mouse scroll-wheel scaling with Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330197/how-to-disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-scaling-with-google-maps-api)**

Answer (score 1):

Или же по методу такого примера - http://jsfiddle.net/0u6v4jnp/.
Как по мне рациональней и удобней.